# Dynamically updating d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This function runs on page load, and also when data is entered in a form. It draws the graph fine on page load, but it doesn't redraw when new info is submitted.

When I log the element after the data join, it shows the updated length of the data array, and the updated number of elements, but they don't redraw. Any ideas, just scanning this code? I feel like it's close, but I'm not understanding the steps of the data updating process.

This is based on the basic bar graph tutorial [let's make a bar chart](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/), which uses divs instead of svg elements, but I don't think that should matter.

```
this.render = function(self){
  if(self.data){
    self.x = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([0, d3.max(self.data.map(function(d) {
                   return parseInt(d.daily_count);
                 }))
               ])
               .range([0, 500]);

    var bars = d3.select("#chart")
                 .selectAll("div")
                 .data(self.data)
                 .enter().append('div')
                   .attr('class', 'bar-container row');

    console.log('chart', d3.select("#chart").data(self.data));

    bars.append('div')
          .attr('class', 'label four columns')
          .text(function(d) {return d.date_string; });

    bars.append("div")
          .attr('class', 'bar eight columns')
          .style('background-color', function(d){
            return (d.daily_count == 0 ? 'white' : '#1EAEDB')
          })
          .style('color', function(d){
            return (d.daily_count == 0 ? 'red' : 'white')
          })
          .style("width", function(d) {
            return self.x(d.daily_count) + "px";
          })
          .text(function(d) {
            return (d.daily_count == 0 ? 'closed' : d.daily_count)
          });
  }
```

EDIT: Attempt to use .merge() and .each() to create and update chart. I can't figure out how to update dynamically where each bar is a div that contains two child divs which actually display the data. This still doesn't work dynamically, although it renders like the above:

```
this.render = function(self){
  if(self.data){
    self.x = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([0, d3.max(self.data.map(function(d) {
                   return parseInt(d.daily_count);
                 }))
               ])
               .range([0, 500]);

    var chart = d3.select("#chart");

    var bars = chart.selectAll("d")
                 .data(self.data)

    bars.enter().append('div')
        .attr('class', 'bar-container row')
        .each(function(d) {
          d3.select(this).append('div')
            .attr('class', 'label four columns');
          d3.select(this).append('div')
            .attr('class', 'bar eight columns');
        })
        .merge(bars)
        .each(function(d){
          d3.select(this).selectAll('div.label')
            .text(function(d) {return d.date_string; });
          d3.select(this).selectAll('div.bar')
            .style('background-color', function(d){
              return (d.daily_count == 0 ? 'white' : '#1EAEDB')
            })
            .style('color', function(d){
              return (d.daily_count == 0 ? 'red' : 'white')
            })
            .style("width", function(d) {
              return self.x(d.daily_count) + "px";
            })
            .text(function(d) {
              return (d.daily_count == 0 ? 'closed' : d.daily_count)
            });
        })

    bars.exit().remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `render` function needs a proper "enter", "update" and "exit" selections. Besides that, have in mind that Bostock's example you linked uses d3 version 3.x, while you're using d3 version 4.x.

In the following demo, this binds the data:

```
var bars = body.selectAll("div")
    .data(data);
```

After that, the "enter" + "update" selections, with the `merge`:

```
bars.enter().append("div")
    .attr("class", "row")
    .merge(bars)
    .style('background-color', function(d){
        return (d.daily_count == 0 ? 'white' : '#1EAEDB')
    })
    .style('color', function(d){
        return (d.daily_count == 0 ? 'red' : 'white')
    })
    .style("width", function(d) {
        return x(d.daily_count) + "px";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        return (d.daily_count == 0 ? 'closed' : d.daily_count)
    });
```

And the exit selection:

```
bars.exit().remove();
```

This is a demo based on your code (using only `daily_count`, because I don't know how you are positioning the other divs):

```js
var dataset = [{daily_count: 19},
{daily_count: 29},
{daily_count: 13},
{daily_count: 45},
{daily_count: 22},
{daily_count: 42},
{daily_count: 9}];

render(dataset)

d3.select("#btn").on("click", function(){
 var newDataset = [];
 var length = Math.ceil(Math.random()*20);
 for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
  newDataset.push({daily_count: Math.floor(Math.random()*50)})
 }
 render(newDataset);
})

function render(data){

    x = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) {
                   return parseInt(d.daily_count);
                 }))
               ])
               .range([0, 300]);
        
  var body = d3.select("body");

    var bars = body.selectAll("div")
                 .data(data);

    bars.enter().append("div")
   .attr("class", "row")
          .merge(bars)
          .style('background-color', function(d){
            return (d.daily_count == 0 ? 'white' : '#1EAEDB')
          })
          .style('color', function(d){
            return (d.daily_count == 0 ? 'red' : 'white')
          })
          .style("width", function(d) {
            return x(d.daily_count) + "px";
          })
          .text(function(d) {
            return (d.daily_count == 0 ? 'closed' : d.daily_count)
          });
     
  bars.exit().remove();

}
```

```css
.row {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 2px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the in-depth answer. I can get it to work when I'm just displaying data in one div per item in the data set, but I've been trying to get this to work with multiple elements, where each item in the data set is displayed with a div and a two child divs (a label and the bar). I put my updated best attempt in an edit of my original answer above, trying to use .each(), which renders correctly, but still doesn't update. What am i still missing here?

Comment: Like, how would you update a div with two child divs in your code snippet? Adding extra elements is throwing me off.

Comment: Please, don't edit your question to ask another question. If my answer helped you, acknowledge it by accepting/upvoting, and post *another* question with your new problem. Bear in mind that in my answer I dealt with just 1 div because I had no idea of your data. So, in the new question, post a sample of the data as well.

Comment: my bad? I didn't think of this as a separate question, and I wasn't about to post code in a comment. here, have your points...